# Editing Supply theme files and script_tag properties in Shopify

Tags: shopify

Question 1 - If I edit Supply theme files, for example merging all the js and css files to increase page load speed.
Will there be any issue, for example do Shopify update some Supply theme files?

Question 2 - Does the script_tag uses async or defer?
Seems like not. I was planning to use async for all the  like [How to async or defer JS in Liquid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47822090/how-to-async-or-defer-js-in-liquid)
Apart from the link below, are there other resources?
https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/html-filters#script_tag

Answer (score 0):

** Question 1 **
Shopify replied with
"
1a - If I have never done any code edit on the liquid files, only then Shopify will auto update the code?
Correct
1b - If I just edit the codes in theme.liquid and add a few liquid files and assets, will Shopify auto update the rest of the untouched liquid and asset files?
This will be a code change and would stop updates.
"

** Question 2 **
Shopify sort of confirmed
"
Script_tag does not use async or defer.
"

These are the best answers from Shopify.