# How to add custom attributes to Shopify's script tag

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I have the following script tag in my `theme.liquid`

```
{{ 'bold-bc-fix.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
```

I'm trying to add a `defer='defer'` attribute to it.

The reason I'm using the shopify script tag instead of a regular script tag is because I was getting a MEME type error without it, apparently it's necessary for for including `.js.liquid` files.

Comment: Provide the specific error you were getting with a "regular script tag." Provide the specific issue you're having with your new method.

Comment: Hi did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47822090/how-to-async-or-defer-js-in-liquid

Comment: @Marc Using the regular script tag doesn't process the liquid in the JS code correctly. Using the Shopify script tag causes my script to run too soon, producing incorrect behaviour.

Comment: @JahanzaibMuneer I didn't, but looking at it now, it's the exact syntax I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

/////////
Try something like this:

```
<script defer src="{{ 'bold-bc-fix.js' | asset_url }}"></script>
```